# OSGi support of org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate

Tags: jetty, osgi, jetty-9

Since version 9.x Jetty seems not to have an aggregate artifact that provides the Jetty server within OSGi environments. It would be very helpful if the project could provide an OSGi compliant aggregate artifact for 9.x and further. In 8.x we had the org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate:jetty-all-server artifact. Why does it not exist for 9.x?

Can anybody help me or has some explanations?

Comment: I do not know the cause of Jetty but in general it is not a good thing to bundle several other OSGi bundles together. By doing that, the aggregated bundle will have many, and in most of the cases many unnecessary dependencies. It is not a big issue outside OSGi as unnecessary dependencies do not have to be installed at runtime, but in OSGi every non-optional Import-Package have to be satisfied. I recommend that you should use those bundles from Jetty that you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregates that exist for Jetty are not meant to be used by projects directly.  They were created specifically for the documentation, and specifically for command line use to demonstrate some of the features of Embedded Jetty use.

It is not recommended to use aggregates for your project.

In fact, jetty-all (a name kept for historical reasons), isn't even "all of jetty" anymore.  This concept isn't even possible anymore, as there are many component options for Jetty that cannot exist in the same jar at the same time.

Would highly recommend using the individual artifacts properly, and with a build tool that supports the [global central repository](http://central.maven.org/), such as maven, ant+ivy, buildr, groovy grape, gradle+grails, scala sbt, or even leiningen.

Once you have a good build setup, you can then pick and choose and setup your own uber jars for jetty that fit your specific needs.  Keep in mind that for OSGi, this would mean having to rewrite the manifest for this uberjar to include all of the OSGi references properly.   Also note, that if you do this, you will likely not play well in the rest of OSGi world that is using Jetty properly.  That is a decision you should make.  Do I play in my own world of OSGi and never use OSGi bundles from other open source projects, or do I want to use other popular OSGi bundles in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I was not aware that the aggregates should not be used in production. Well, actually my project is based on Maven, but its becoming bigger and bigger, so I was looking for some aggregation changes.